# Query to insert into multple table from one select query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, select, sql-insert

Probably a noob question and there are workaround, but just to know if any SQL expert can provide a better solution for this:

We know about this query:

```
Insert INTO table1 (column1, column2)  
Select column1, column2 
FROM table2
```

But i was wondering if there is a way to insert into multiple table using this query? As i've a select statement that provide a table of data which i needed to insert into multiple table. This option is purely for data migration case, and i don't want to use `cursor`. So any alternatives?

Comment: Is it SQL Server or MySql?

Comment: Any, SQL or MySQL, or even plSQL.

Comment: Ok, I think my answer below still stands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot insert records into multiple tables inside one query.

What you can do though is to insert data into a temporary table first. Then you can insert into multiple tables from your temp table (inserting into one table at the time). This way you won't have to select the data multiple times.

Comment: I'll wait for another day or so to see if anyone else have any opinion. After that i'll accept your answer (1st paragraph of your answer).